# Highcharts: dynamically updating chart per click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Note: I have already read this question: [Highcharts - Dyanmic graph with no initial data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15162891/highcharts-dyanmic-graph-with-no-initial-data)

And the effect I want to achieve is similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/7vZ5a/40/. However, instead of updating every second, I would like it to update per click of a button. This is what I get so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/7vZ5a/49/

```
$(function() {
  var chartData = [50, 60, 70, 100, 120, 200];
  var timeStamps = [];
  var index = 1;
  $('#b').click(function() {
    timeStamps.push(new Date());
    var buttonB = document.getElementById('b');
    buttonB.disabled = true;
    if (index < chartData.length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (index == 1) {
          $('#container').highcharts().series[0].addPoint([0, chartData[0]], true, false);
          $('#container').highcharts().series[0].addPoint([index, chartData[index]], true, false);
        } else {
          $('#container').highcharts().series[0].addPoint([index, chartData[index]], true, true);
           index++;
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
    if (index < chartData.length - 1) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        buttonB.disabled = false;
      }, 1500);
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() {
        buttonB.style.visibility = "hidden";
      }, 1500);
    }
    if (index == chartData.length - 2) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('b').innerHTML = 'Letzte Ziehung';
      }, 1000);
    }
    console.log(timeStamps);
  })
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
      decimalPoint: ','
    },
  });
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'line',
      marginBottom: 60
    },
    colors: [
      '#0000ff',
    ],
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Time',
        offset: 23
      },

      min: 0,
      max: 1,
      tickInterval: 1,
      gridLineWidth: 1

    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Value'
      },
      min: 0,
      max: 200
    },
    plotOptions: {
      line: {
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + 'GE';
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
      name: '',
      data: []
    }]
  });
});
```

Why (almost) the same code could work on the case when the chart update automatically but not on the case when the update is triggered by click?
(I also tried the function with the code controlling update not in "setTimeout" block, it also did not work.)

Comment: you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7vZ5a/43/ ? if this is what you want I can explain to you in an answer how it works

Comment: @SimonHänisch Yes, exactly. Thank you!

Comment: @SimonHänisch Would you also tell me in your answer why my code in http://jsfiddle.net/7vZ5a/46/ does not work?

Comment: I will have a look at it

Comment: Here you can see working example of how you can make your chart http://jsfiddle.net/7vZ5a/52/ In your example you have min and max of your xAxis so you cannot see the line that is outside this values. Look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/7vZ5a/54/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is create a function that adds data to a series, like:

```
function addData(series, data) {
    series.addPoint([series.length, data], true, false);
}
```

This for example adds a new point with value `data` to the end of `series` (indexed `series.length`, which is one index higher than the last index of the series).

Then you can bind this function to the click event of your button:

```
$('#add-random-data').on('click', function () {
    addData(chart.series[0], Math.random());
});
```

This adds a random value between `0` and `1` to the series. It is assumed that the chart is stored in a variable named `chart`, and `series[0]` is the series of that chart that you want to add the data to.

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vZ5a/55/) shows this on the given example chart.

The reason why your code doesn't work is that you set `min` and `max` of your x-axis, as pointed out in the comments. That way the chart won't plot data that is indexed outside of your limits. You can just let the chart auto-scale its axes by removing the `min` and `max` properties. If you want the values to always be between `0` and `1` on the x-axis, you have to overwrite the points with index `0` and `1` in your series.

Comment: How do you "overwrite the points with index 0 and 1"? I tried to do this in this context (dynamically updating chart), however, the desired effect is not achieved.

Comment: you can either use the [Series.setData](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData()) method or remove the previous points from the series first with [Series.removePoint()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.removePoint).

Comment: (Thanks for all the examples!) Is it possible to show the 0 on x-axis before the botton is clicked?

Comment: I recommend reading the API docs, I never worked with highcharts before but they tell me everything I needed in order to help you ;) => http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Comment: You can just add some initial zero value to the series, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7vZ5a/61/ I guess it's also possible to (re)draw the plot/axes with empty data somehow

Comment: Well from what I can see I think you need to set `min` and `max` in order to get the axes plotted before there is any data in your chart... but you can change them on data changes using [Axis.setExtremes()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes) (or possibly remove them using `setExtremes(undefined, undefined)` or `setExtremes(null, null)`).